# Three.js Make static cube

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm newbie in Three.js, so, I'm trying just to make STATIC cube. So, I've found a rotating cube example. Here it is:

```
var camera, scene, renderer;
var mesh;

init();
animate();
//renderer.render( scene, camera );
function init() {

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
    camera.position.z = 400;

    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( '16.jpg' );
    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 200, 200, 200 );
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture } );
    var axes = new THREE.AxisHelper( 20 );


    mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    scene.add( mesh );

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

}

function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    mesh.rotation.x += 0.005;
    mesh.rotation.y += 0.01;

    renderer.render( scene, camera );

}
```

ok, everything work fine. Now I want to make just STATIC cube, I've wrote

```
var camera, scene, renderer;
var mesh;

init();
renderer.render( scene, camera );
function init() {

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
    camera.position.z = 400;

    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( '16.jpg' );
    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 200, 200, 200 );
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture } );
    var axes = new THREE.AxisHelper( 20 );


    mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    scene.add( mesh );

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

}
```

The output is just a black screen, what have I done wrong?

Comment: Well, what happens?  I expect you're not seeing the cube, and that's probably because you still need to call  animate() {
            requestAnimationFrame( animate );
            renderer.render( scene, camera );

        }

Comment: Nothing - just empty space!:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The texture loading is asynchronous, and you are rendering the scene before it is done.
Add a callback to the Image Loader and render again:

```
var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('16.jpg', undefined, function () {
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
});
```

Alternatively render continuosly with `requestAnimationFrame`:

```
init();
animate();

//...

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it looks like when you got rid of `animate()`, you also got rid of the call to

`renderer.render( scene, camera );`

so you need to put that back in the code somewhere to render your scene

Comment: but I've made it just after `init()` function

Comment: oh oops, i didn't see that, sorry